# how to synchronize 2 data generated from 2 different devices

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, synchronization

I have a 2 Insole (left and right insole), then 2 data generated from the left and right insole will be sent to firebase every 1 second. To send data per second I use 2 timers namely **left_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate** and **right_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate** but the data generated from these 2 insoles is still out of sync. because the resulting data is messy. the reason the resulting data is messy is that if we walk only one foot will step on the insole. but with this code, two feet will be on the ground when we walk. I suspect this delay is due to the process of sending data. is there any solution for this problem

Here My code:

connectLeftBtn:

```
     connectLeftBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked)
                {
                    connectDevice(L_insole_mac);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (is_L_insole_connected)
                        if(is_L_insole_started)
                            left_insole_device_interface.stopInsole();
                    startLeftBtn.setText("Start Left");
                    is_L_insole_started = false;
                    bluetoothManager.closeDevice(left_insole_device_interface);
                    is_L_insole_connected = false;
                    Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Left Insole Disconnected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            private void connectDevice(String mac) {
                bluetoothManager.openSerialDevice(mac)
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(this::onConnected, this::onError);
            }
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            private void onConnected(BluetoothSerialDevice connectedDevice) {
                // You are now connected to this device!
                // Here you may want to retain an instance to your device:
                left_insole_device_interface = connectedDevice.toSimpleDeviceInterface();

                // Listen to bluetooth events
                left_insole_device_interface.setListeners(message -> onMessageReceived(message), this::onMessageSent, this::onError);
                left_insole_device_interface.stopInsole();

                is_L_insole_connected = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Connected to Left Insole.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            private void onMessageReceived(String message) {
                //store incoming bytes temporarily
                if(!is_L_insole_started){
                    left_temp_bytes+=message+" ";
                }
                //check whether the start_bytes exits in the temporary buffer
                if(!is_L_insole_started && left_temp_bytes.contains(start_bytes)){
                    is_L_insole_started = true;
                    left_temp_bytes ="";
                }
                //if the start_bytes are found in the temporary buffer, start storing the incoming messages in the actual buffer
                if(is_L_insole_started){
                    left_data_len++;
                    if(left_data_len>15) {
                        left_sensor_data_count++;
                        if (!non_sensor_indeces.contains(left_sensor_data_count)) {
                            l_data_double_arr[left_data_index] = Double.parseDouble(message);
//                            System.out.println("NON SENSOR INDEX:" + left_data_index + " "+ message);
                            left_data_index++;
                        }
                    }

                    Date date = new Date();

                    leftDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)), Arrays.toString(l_data_double_arr));
                    

                    //if the data length reach the max_data_length, release the buffer and invert the start flag
                    if(left_data_len>=max_data_len+15){
                        heatMapLeft.clearData();
                        for(int i=0; i<x_L.length; i++) {
                            HeatMap.DataPoint point =  new HeatMap.DataPoint(x_L[i], y[i], l_data_double_arr[i]);
                            heatMapLeft.addData(point);
                            heatMapLeft.forceRefresh();
                        }

                        left_package_count++;
                        left_data_index= 0;
                        left_sensor_data_count = 0;
                        left_data_len=0;
                        is_L_insole_started=false;
                    }
                }
            }
            private void onMessageSent(String message) {
                // We sent a message! Handle it here.
//                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Sent a message! Message was: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Replace context with your context instance.
            }

            private void onError(Throwable error) {
                // Handle the error
            }

        });
```

connectRightBtn:

```
connectRightBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
    
                    if (isChecked) {
                        connectDevice(R_insole_mac);
    
                    } else {
                        if (is_R_insole_connected) {
                            if (is_R_insole_started) {
                                right_insole_device_interface.stopInsole();
                                startRightBtn.setText("Start Right");
                                is_R_insole_started = false;
                            }
                            bluetoothManager.closeDevice(right_insole_device_interface);
                            is_R_insole_connected = false;
                            Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Right Insole Disconnected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                private void connectDevice (String mac){
                    bluetoothManager.openSerialDevice(mac)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(this::onConnected, this::onError);
                }
    
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                private void onConnected (BluetoothSerialDevice connectedDevice){
                    // You are now connected to this device!
                    // Here you may want to retain an instance to your device:
                    right_insole_device_interface = connectedDevice.toSimpleDeviceInterface();
    
                    // Listen to bluetooth events
                    right_insole_device_interface.setListeners(message -> onMessageReceived(message), this::onMessageSent, this::onError);
                    right_insole_device_interface.stopInsole();
    
                    is_R_insole_connected = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Connected to Right Insole.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    
                private void onMessageSent (String message){
                    // We sent a message! Handle it here.
                }
    
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                private void onMessageReceived (String message){
                    //store incoming bytes temporarily
                    if(!is_R_insole_started){
                        right_temp_bytes+=message+" ";
                    }
                    //check whether the start_bytes exits in the temporary buffer
                    if(!is_R_insole_started && right_temp_bytes.contains(start_bytes)){
                        is_R_insole_started = true;
                        right_temp_bytes ="";
                    }
                    //if the start_bytes are found in the temporary buffer, start storing the incoming messages in the actual buffer
                    if(is_R_insole_started){
                        right_data_len++;
                        if(right_data_len>15) {
                            right_sensor_data_count++;
                            if (!non_sensor_indeces.contains(right_sensor_data_count)) {
                                r_data_double_arr[right_data_index] = Double.parseDouble(message);
    //                                System.out.println("NON SENSOR INDEX:" + right_data_index + " "+ message);
                                right_data_index++;
                            }
                        }
    
                        Date date = new Date();
                        rightDataDict.put(String.valueOf(formatter.format(date)),Arrays.toString(r_data_double_arr));
    
    //                        if the data length reach the max_data_length, release the buffer and invert the start flag
                        if(right_data_len>=max_data_len+15){
                            heatMapRight.clearData();
                            for(int i=0; i<x_R.length; i++) {
                                HeatMap.DataPoint point =  new HeatMap.DataPoint(x_R[i], y[i], r_data_double_arr[i]);
                                heatMapRight.addData(point);
                                heatMapRight.forceRefresh();
                            }
    
                            right_data_index= 0;
                            right_sensor_data_count = 0;
                            right_data_len=0;
                            is_R_insole_started=false;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
    
                private void onError(Throwable error) {
                    // Handle the error
                }
            });
```

startLeftBtn:

```
startLeftBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (is_L_insole_connected) {
                        if (is_L_insole_started) {
                            left_insole_device_interface.stopInsole();
                            is_L_insole_started = false;
                            startLeftBtn.setText("Start Left");
                            left_timer.cancel();
    
                        } else {
                            left_insole_device_interface.startInsole();
                            is_L_insole_started = true;
                            startLeftBtn.setText("Stop Left");
    
                            left_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                                        public void run() {
    //                                        Log.d("TAG", "Hashmap: "+ leftDataDict);
                                            sendToFirebase(leftDataDict, "Left_Insole");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            },1000, 1000);
    
                            Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Left Insole Started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                        }
                    }else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Left Insole Not Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
    
                }
            });
```

startRightBtn:

```
startRightBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    if(is_R_insole_connected) {
                        if (is_R_insole_started) {
                            right_insole_device_interface.stopInsole();
                            is_R_insole_started = false;
                            startRightBtn.setText("Start Right");
                            right_timer.cancel();
                        } else {
                            right_insole_device_interface.startInsole();
                            is_R_insole_started = true;
                            startRightBtn.setText("Stop Right");
    
                            right_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            sendToFirebase(rightDataDict, "Right_Insole");
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            },1000, 1000);
    
                            Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Right Insole Started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Right Insole Not Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

SendToFirebase:

```
public void sendToFirebase(Map<String,Object>  data, String of_insole){
            Date date = new Date();
            db.collection("Experiments").document(PATIENT_NAME).set(patientRecord);
            db.collection("Experiments")
                    .document(PATIENT_NAME)
                    .collection(of_insole)
                    .document(String.valueOf(formatter2.format(date)))
                    .set(data)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                            data.clear();
                            Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Succesfully saved to Firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Visualization.this, "Failed to saved to Firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **300** (three hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.  Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't seem to have less than 300 lines of code.